# Substratum themes not applying (Nexus 6P, Dirty Unicorns 12.1 Oreo)

Tags: custom-roms, nexus-6p, themes

I have the problem of Substratum themes not applying on my Nexus 6P using Dirty Unicorns 12.1 (latest version).

I can choose an installed theme in Substratum, choose all the settings I want, and hit compile - that's all going well. Substratum tells me it compiled everything correctly, then, when applying, it restarts the SystemUI and boom - nothing. Nothing has changed and when I check back in the Substratum app, it neither lists the theme as compiled nor as applied.

This happens for all themes, I've tried a dozen or two.
It's extremely sad, as themability is *the* reason for me owning an Android device with custom ROM.

Info about DU: AFAIK, DU 12.1 has native built-in support for OMS.

Answer (score 0):

Switching off Play Protect (apparently, there is some kind of issue with the recent version of Play Service) and switching on Firebase did the trick.

Comment: Curious how you switch on Firebase, since Firebase is usually on the developer-side, not the client-side?